# me sale error archivo batch Número no válido

Tags: windows, cmd, batch

que tal estoy construyendo un .bat el cual si me sirve pero hoy lo ejecute y me mando el siguiente error
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es el archivo

```
pushd \\192.168.23.1\bancomer2\Respaldo_A200
set /a fecha=%date:~0,2% -1
MKDIR  "%fecha%"
copy \\10.100.14.12\Sterling\Recibe\R200_CMG.txt  \\192.168.23.1\bancomer2\Respaldo_A200\"%fecha%"\R200_CMG.txt
copy \\10.100.14.12\Sterling\Recibe\GEST_CMG.txt  \\192.168.23.1\bancomer2\Respaldo_A200\"%fecha%"\GEST_CMG.txt
start %windir%\explorer.exe "\\192.168.23.1\bancomer2\Respaldo_A200\"%fecha%"\"
pushd c:\ruta
MKDIR  "%fecha%"
set /a fecha=%date:~0,2% -1
nircmd.exe cmdwait 5000 savescreenshot  C:\ruta\img.png
pushd c:\Users\robertomendoza.CMGREFORMA\Downloads
start Excel.exe impresion.xls
```

lo unico que haces es tomar fecha del dia siguiente y crear una carpeta despues tomar captura de pantalla y abrir un excel

Comment: Esto te ha funcionado alguna vez? La opción `/a` [evalúa una expresión numérica](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/set_1) y se la asigna al string dado

Comment: si ya me a funcionando si funcionaba diario pero hoy no me agarro y me arrojo ese error

Answer (score 1):

Probé el fragmento problemático de tu código varias veces y nunca conseguí que funcionara como indicas.

Si yo hago

```
set /a fecha=%date:~0,2% -1
echo %fecha%
```

La salida me indica que lo que obtengo de la fecha no es numérico (sólo da las dos primeras letras del día de la semana) y sólo usa el -1

```
C:\Workspace\tmp>pepito1.bat

C:\Workspace\tmp>set /a fecha=Mo -1

C:\Workspace\tmp>echo -1
```

Esto seguramente tiene que ver con la configuración regional, posiblemente también estés obteniendo un "Lu" o algo así.
Posiblemente cambió el locale de tu máquina o se actualizó algo que lo devolvió a otra configuración. Lo otro es que posiblemente te funcionó para días posteriores al 10, pues con 01-09 eso entrega números que el batch va a identificar como octales.

La forma adecuada de no depender de estas situaciones es obtener los valores como lo muestra [esta respuesta](https://serverfault.com/a/227375/51124) y obtener el día siguiente de otra forma:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

rem Get the time from WMI - at least that's a format we can work with
set X=
for /f "skip=1 delims=" %%x in ('wmic os get localdatetime') do if not defined X set X=%%x
echo.%X%

rem dissect into parts
set DATE.YEAR=%X:~0,4%
set DATE.MONTH=%X:~4,2%
set DATE.DAY=%X:~6,2%
set DATE.HOUR=%X:~8,2%
set DATE.MINUTE=%X:~10,2%
set DATE.SECOND=%X:~12,2%
set DATE.FRACTIONS=%X:~15,6%
set DATE.OFFSET=%X:~21,4%

set /a "DATE.DAYPLUS=1%DATE.DAY% %% 100+1"

echo %DATE.YEAR%-%DATE.MONTH%-%DATE.DAY% %DATE.HOUR%:%DATE.MINUTE%:%DATE.SECOND%.%DATE.FRACTIONS%

echo.%DATE.DAYPLUS% es siguiente dia
```

Aquí puedes usar `%DATE.DAY%` y manipularlo usando [un hack horrendo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14527726/236345) en `cmd` que es básicamente convertir tu día a número (anteponiendo un `1` y usando módulo 100 para que quede el valor original, evitando así el problema con los días anteriores a 10) para poderle sumar 1 y obtener el número de día. La salida del batch propuesto es:

```
C:\Workspace\tmp>pepito1.bat
20201109124446.161000-300
2020-11-09 12:44:46.161000
10 es siguiente dia
```

Para el día anterior, modificas la asignación a DATE.DAYPLUS **solamente** para evitar los errores mencionados

```
set /a "DATE.DAYPLUS=1%DATE.DAY% %% 100-1"
```

¿¿¿¿Ves el `-1` al final????

Todo lo anterior para decir: ¿No has pensado en pasarte a usar scripts en PowerShell? :)

Comment: y como puedo hacer para que me tome entonces la fecha del dia anterior

Comment: Pues usando -1 al armar la variable DAYPLUS. Prueba

Comment: a ok vale lo agrege asi y me dio el dia de hoy set DAY=%X:~6,2% -1

Comment: La variable DATE.DAYPLUS. Revisa dónde estoy armando el día siguiente. Lo estás haciendo donde no es y vas a tener el mismo problema que te expliqué de los números que no se identifican como números decimales.

Comment: MKDIR  "%DATE.DAYPLUS%" asi pensaba hacer carpeta

Comment: creo que mas bien con que tome las decimales estaria bien para los dias que son antes del 10